# Maya UI Python change NumberOfCollums dynamically

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I want to change (kind of dynamically) the NumberOfColumns of a rowColumnLayout inside a Maya Window. Depending on the value given by 'SLiBThumbSizeComboBox' i want to change the count for the columns.

Here is the problem: when running my 2 functions inside the Script Editor everything is working fine. I execute the first one - the ScrollLayout is created. I execute the second and the rowColumnLayout is created with the right count of columns.

But when I try run it only by the first function, meaning the second function is called at the end of the first one - it's not working anymore?! I get the error message, that NumberOfCollumns has to be greater than 0 ?!

```
def FunctionA():
    if cmds.scrollLayout('SLiBScrollLayout', query = True, exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI('SLiBScrollLayout', layout = True)
    cmds.scrollLayout('SLiBScrollLayout', p="SLiB_thumbsframe")

def FunctionB():
    iconLayout = cmds.optionMenu('SLiBThumbSizeComboBox', query = True, value = True)
    iconSize = iconLayout.split('x')
    iconDiv = int(iconSize[0])
    n = int(cmds.scrollLayout("SLiBScrollLayout", query=True, saw=1)/iconDiv)
    cmds.rowColumnLayout('Icons', numberOfColumns=n, p="SLiBScrollLayout")
```

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised the rowColumnlayout complains if you give it zero columns: you'll always need 1.  Depending on how the are setting up the gui , your query on `saw` might return 0, which would explain your problem.

Here's a very basic example of what it looks like your trying to do:

```
w = cmds.window()
c = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
v_slider = cmds.intSlider(min = 1, max =10, value=2)
h_slider = cmds.intSlider(min = 1, max =10, value=2)
scroll = cmds.scrollLayout()
form = cmds.formLayout()
def update_row(*_):
    # get the row and column counts
    rows = cmds.intSlider(v_slider, q=True, v= True)
    columns = cmds.intSlider(h_slider, q=True, v= True)

    # delete the old layout and rebuild. 
    # the 'or []` below lets you loop even if there are no children....
    for n in cmds.formLayout(form, q=True, ca=True) or []:
        cmds.deleteUI(n)
    cmds.setParent(form)

    # make a new rowColumn
    new_row = cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc = columns)
    for n in range(rows * columns):
        cmds.button(label="button_%i" % n)
    cmds.formLayout(form, e=True, af = [(new_row,'top',0), (new_row, 'bottom', 0 ), (new_row,  'left', 0 ), (new_row, 'right', 0)])

# both sliders call the update function
cmds.intSlider(h_slider, e=True, cc =update_row)
cmds.intSlider(v_slider, e=True, cc =update_row)
update_row()  # do it once to get started
cmds.showWindow(w)
```

The key here is the order in which it's declared: the function knows what `v_slider`, `h_slider` and `form` are because it's declared after them and doesn't need to do extra work to find them (you can get a more controlled version of the same effect with a class. You'll notice I don't use the names at all: names are unreliable if there's an old layout lying around, it's simpler to use variables.

I've also set the minimum values for the row and columns to 1 so there's no zero division problem.

Comment: First thank you very much for the reply! As i wrote the saw gives me a number and it is actually working but only if i execute the "collumn update" as seperate function via a button mouse click. But I'm always interested in new ideas. As for your script  - is the only way to update the collum count to use the sliders? I would like to have it triggered by the window size?! Thanks Daniel

Comment: Unfortunately there's no resize event I'm aware of -- It's probably there in the underlying QT widget but the default maya.cmds windows don't tell you when you resize.  You could  maybe do it with a dragCallback inside a big button, but it would be pushing the Maya gui beyond what it's good at